# JQuery edit DataTable Sort event

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to edit the sort event in `jquery.dataTable`?
I want to change the color of table rows, when I sort a column, while they're already filtered by a search input.

```
$('.results').dataTable({
    "bSort":true, //this one
    "aaSorting": [],
    "bFilter":false,
    "paging":false,
    "bPaginate":false,
    "bInfo":false
});
```

**EDIT**

My working code:

```
$('.results').dataTable({
    "bSort":true,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "bFilter":false,
    "bPaginate":false,
    "bInfo":false,
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        if(this.fnSettings().bSorted)
            console.log("Sort fired");
    }
});
```

PS: added this.fnSettings().bSorted to detect what event is fired paging, filtering, sorting, etc.

Comment: not 100% sure what your trying to do so i wont post an answer but you could probably do something with the ordering event https://datatables.net/reference/event/order though i dont know what version of data tables your using and that event in 1.10 +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Possible to edit sort event: google "datatables sort event" and read the first link you find.
2. Change color of table rows: google "datatables change default styling" and read the first link you find.
3. When you sort a column: see #1.
4. While they're already filtered by a search input: google "datatables check if filter is applied" and read the first link you find.

Once you've done this research and applied it to your problem, if you still aren't able to completely solve it, then you might post back with more specific questions about the problems that you're having.

One thing I'll explain for you since it isn't entirely obvious.  Newer versions of DataTables have gotten away from all those obscure prefixes for options, and now just use a descriptive word.  However, they kept the old versions for backward compatibility reasons.  So, in your code example, `paging` is the newer version of `bPaginate` and they do the same thing.  `bSort` is now `orderable`, `aaSorting` is now `order`, `bInfo` is now `info`, and `bFilter` is now `searching`.  Since `bFilter: false` turns off the search capability, you probably want to remove it to get what you want, because "while they're already filtered by a search input" is not something that can exist when you've specified an option that removes the search input.

Comment: Hungarian notation is the technical name for those "obscure prefixes", just in case anybody wanted to know.

Comment: @ChrisH.  Well, now, that's interesting.  I still have remnants of the habit from my old VB6 days: btnThis, txtThat, selTheOther. But I never put two and two together on these, so I did an archaeological dig and sure enough: aa (as in 'aaSorting`) is an array of arrays indicating multiple sort order, b is boolean, i is integer, s is string, ao is array of objects, m is mixed.  When I started in with DataTables five years ago, I saw a, aa and b and figured that Allan was using a convention known only to himself, and didn't see the prefixes as type indicators.  Good call!

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
You're right, it's the old version, but i didn't change it,
I'll use the old options with fnDrawCallback funcction,
my current working code:

    $('.results').dataTable({
        "bSort":true,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bFilter":false,
        "paging":false,
        "bPaginate":false,
        "bInfo":false,
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            if(this.fnSettings().bSorted)
                console.log("Sort fired");
        },
    });

PS: added this.fnSettings().bSorted to detect what event is fired paging, filtering, sorting...

Comment: No reason to change it, but you don't need to use both `bPaginate` and `paging`.  They are the same thing in different versions; you can remove one or the other.  If your code is now working, it would be helpful to others if you edit your post and add it to the bottom.  (Don't replace the old code, because that will confuse people who are trying to solve the same problem you've had.)